# is CARRIAGECONTROL= ' NONE ' option a standard f90 IO?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I want to access a text file in a C-like fashion. The option CARRIAGECONTROL= 'NONE' apparently achieves this, [according to this page](http://cftcc.iccas.ac.cn/upload/doc/ifc/f_ug1/format_of_record_types_.htm#Stream). Is it a standard option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "C-like fashion" you mean read the file as a stream of bytes, there was no standard way to do this before Fortran 2003. However many compilers offered it as an extension, like the manual of the Intel compiler on the webpage you refered to.
Since Fortran 2003, there is a standard way of opening a file for stream access which is

```
ACCESS='STREAM'
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard option is access='stream' in the open statement

In F77, this was not standardized and often compiler dependent.